# My Fill-the-circles puzzles (Set # 1)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

In each puzzle, fill the circles with the numbers 1, 2, 3, ... n, where n is the number of circles in such a way that consecutive numbers are NOT in circles that are joined with a line.

[image: 4 circles]

[image: 5 circles]

[image: 6 circles]

[image: 7 circles]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the solutions:

> [image: solutions to puzzles]
>
>  In each of the puzzles, there's a special circle (highlighted in yellow below):
>
>  [image: blank puzzles; several circles are colored yellow and orange]
>
>  Each yellow circle has a special property - it connects to *all other circles* but one, the one marked in orange. This means it can't be in the middle of the sequence - it must be at one of the two ends. The symmetric counterparts of the yellow circles also have this property. This lets you place numbers 1, 2, $n$, and $n-1$ immediately; the rest of the circles are easy to fill.